# What are the differences between tickinterval and minTickInterval in HighCharts? Please explain

Tags: highcharts

What are the differences between tickinterval and minTickInterval in HighCharts?
I have tried in with many resources  but could not get info.
Please explain

Answer (score 0):

`tickInterval` sets the interval of tick marks in an axis, the `minTickInterval` sets the smallest tick interval allowed in an axis.

**minTickInterval**

*The minimum tick interval allowed in axis values. For example on zooming in on an axis with daily data, this can be used to prevent the axis from showing hours. Defaults to the closest distance between two points on the axis.*

**tickInterval**

*The interval of the tick marks in axis units. When undefined, the tick interval is computed to approximately follow the tickPixelInterval on linear and datetime axes. On categorized axes, a undefined tickInterval will default to 1, one category. Note that datetime axes are based on milliseconds, so for example an interval of one day is expressed as 24 * 3600 * 1000.*